# In WPF / C#, how can I check if the center button is clicked or released?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseclick-event

In WPF / C#, there are events on MouseRightButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonDown, but what about the center mouse button?

Is the Center Mouse button down/up e.g. events in WPF forgotten?

How can I check if the center button is clicked or released?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the MouseDown/MouseUp event and check the MouseButtonEventArgs:

```
private void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Middle)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, great! That was an easy one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`MouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mousedown.aspx) and [`MouseUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mouseup.aspx) events:

> You should use the **MouseDown** event and check the [MiddleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.middlebutton.aspx) state in the event arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle MouseDown event and in event handler you can check which Mouse Button was pressed by using

```
if(e.ChangedButton == System.Windows.Input.MouseButton.Middle)
{
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a direct event handler defined for Up or Down events. The only thing we could do is handle the MouseDown event and check the MiddleButton state like so,

```
void Window1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.MiddleButton.ToString());
    }
```